# How do I get the Else message to get printed only once?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement, go

In the code below if the user enters an incorrect API name to find the `else` statement prints the "unable to find" message every time it goes through an item in the `apis.Items` array. But I only want the error message printed once. Like after going through all the items in the `apis.Items` array if there is no item with the name provided by the user the program should print the "unable to find" message. How do I achieve this.
Ps: I'm new to this language

```
for _, item := range apis.Items {
        if item.Name == apiName {
            fmt.Printf("API ID found: %+v ", item.Id)
            api_id := item.Id 
            cmd_2, err := exec.Command("aws", "apigateway", "get-export", "--rest-api-id", api_id, "--stage-name", stageName, "--export-type", "swagger", "/home/akshitha/Documents/" + apiName + ".json").Output()
            if err != nil {
                utils.HandleErrorAndExit("Error getting API swagger", err)
            }
            output := string(cmd_2[:])
            fmt.Println(output)
            break
        }else {
            fmt.Println("Unable to fine an API with the name " + apiName)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a variable when the `item` is found. If not found then `print` it `outside` the loop.

Like this:

```golang
var found bool

for _, item := range apis.Items {
    if item.Name == apiName {
        fmt.Printf("API ID found: %+v ", item.Id)
        api_id := item.Id
        cmd_2, err := exec.Command("aws", "apigateway", "get-export", "--rest-api-id", api_id, "--stage-name", stageName, "--export-type", "swagger", "/home/akshitha/Documents/"+apiName+".json").Output()
        if err != nil {
            utils.HandleErrorAndExit("Error getting API swagger", err)
        }
        output := string(cmd_2[:])
        fmt.Println(output)

        found = true
        
        break
    }
}
if !found {
    fmt.Println("Unable to fine an API with the name " + apiName)
}
```

Comment: this is great ! and simple

Comment: If you have this in a function and nothing else after, you can just `return` (instead of `break`), removing the need for the `found` variable.